# Do all Crypto Coins use the same Wallet Format?

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat, altcoin

There are many crypto currencies now, BTC, LTC, MTC, Potcoin and so on. Each of these have their own wallet.dat files used by the client software.

My question is: Do all these crypto currencies make use of the same format of wallet.dat file?

pywallet.py can be used to dump the keys from a BTC wallet.dat file.

Can pywallet.py also be used to dump the information from a wallet of an alternate crypto currency like LTC/MTC and so on?

Answer (score 2):

The wallet.dat is a Berkeley DB file.
You can parse it using following command (You need to install Berkeley DB on your unix environement first)

```
db_dump wallet.dat
```

I checked for Bitcoin and Litecoin and in both case the wallet.dat was using the same version of Berkeley DB.

```
VERSION=3
format=bytevalue
database=main
type=btree
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END
```

I haven't try pywallet.py but I guess it should work for all these Bitcoin derived altcoins.